# PHP Symfony how can I make this URL query name more user friendly

Tags: php, symfony

I have made a controller class that produces a form once the user has inputted the values and submitted the form I have got it to pass one of the form values into the URL.

Issue is it looks like this:

`localhost/task/success?0=History`

Here is my code for the controller class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Task;
use App\Form\TaskType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TaskController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/task', name: 'task')]
    public function taskForm(Request $request): Response
    {
        $task = new Task();

        $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success', (array)$task->getTask());
            //return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success'            (array)$request->request->get($task->getTask()));
        }

        return $this->render('Task/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
    #[Route('/task/success', name:'task_success')]
    public function taskResult(Request $request): Response
    {
        $query = $request->query->get('0');
        return $this->render('Task/test.html.twig',[
            'task' => $query,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How can I make it so the query isn't 0= and so that it is say the name of the textfield that being task in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting the `$task->getTask()` to an array, which will do a string to array conversion, and create an array with index `0`.

To fix this, you want to name the parameter.

```php
public function taskForm(Request $request): Response
{
// ...
    return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success', ['task' => $task->getTask()]);
// ...
}
```

You can then grab the query parameter `task`.

```php
public function taskResult(Request $request): Response
{
    $query = $request->query->get('task');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else that I can do improve the controler class. I am new to coding in PHP Symfony you see

Comment: Nothing much to see here ofcourse. But if you want to improve it, you can add a list of allowed methods to your `Route`'s so they only react to these methods. The second thing is that you may not even have to redirect to the `/success` url at all. But that completely depends on your use-case.  That something we can not  really decide.